# Closing window in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, skype

I am having a visitor fill out and submit a form.  If their data includes a skype name, i would like to attempt to launch skype without them clicking on a button to launch it.  I thought i could do it by opening a new window with the url of `skype:mySkypeName?call`, but i cant seem to close the new window (it works fine if the address of the new window is http).  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried opening the url in an invisible iframe? That wouldn't need closing.

Comment: i can believe i completely glazed over that possibility.  Thank you, works perfectly.